# Nvidia external monitor hdmi output corrupt image not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, multiple-monitors, hdmi

After struggling for many many hours, **I finally got to make my second (external) monitor to work with Ubuntu**.

Here is my system details:

- Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop
- GeForce GTX 965M (laptop)

When I plugged my external monitor the image was pretty much like
this one:

[image: this one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Ubuntu's 16.04 embedded Kernel 4.4 is known to have incompatibilities with some graphic cards. So the deal here is to **upgrade to a newer Kernel**.

1. Remove nvidia from your system

> ```
> sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
> sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
> ```

2. Reboot

> ```
> sudo reboot
> ```

3. Upgrade kernel (Read [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus))

> ```
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
> ```

4. Another reboot and your external monitor should work